# Can we make a suitable choice of y-axis in proving that any translation or rotation is the product of two reflections?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, proof-explanation, transformation, isometry

In the book Geometry of Surface, John Stillwell proves that:

*Any translation or rotation is the product of two reflections.*

He starts with the translations. The proof starts with

> By suitable choice of $y$-axis (namely, as a line parallel to the direction of translation) we can assume that the given translation is $t_{(0,\delta)}$.

I'm having trouble with this "suitable" choice, because in doing this we are actually doing a conjugation with a map that brings a line to the $y$-axis. And how do we know that this conjugation is still a product of two reflections? It seems like unsound reasoning to me. Can I get comments on this?

Here the translation $t_{(\alpha, \beta)}$ of $O$ to $(\alpha, \beta)$ is given by $x' = \alpha + x$ and $y' = \beta + y$.

Comment: I fixed the typo

Answer (score 0):

The claim can be proven by simple euclidean geometry without introducing coordinates. I think he drew an auxiliary $y$-axis in order to explain the intended geometric construction.

Comment: I have added the definition of the translation. I'm not sure what you mean presicely with simple euclidean geometry. The approach that Stillwell takes seems to be analytical geometry: the cartesian plane with coordinates. He gave a figure for the intuition of the argument, but he gave an actual calculation as a proof (the calculation was done with the suitable choice).

Comment: @JensWagemaker You can have a coordinate-free definition of isometry on a Euclidean plane over which you then impose Cartesian coordinates when convenient--which may be practically all the time. I don't have a copy of the book so I don't know whether Stillwell actually defines translations as coordinate transformations; perhaps the coordiinates occur only in the context of _naming_ a particular translation $t_{(\alpha,\beta)}.$

Comment: @DavidK, do you have a reference to a book where they give a coordinate free definition of isometry? And do they also give coordinate free definitions of translation, rotation and reflection? Or is this not possible?

Comment: @JensWagemaker I don't have a specific book in mind, but consider classical constructions that copy a figure from one place to another in the Euclidean plane. The idea of using coordinates to do that sort of thing is a relative novelty.

Answer (score 0):

If $\Pi$ is a reflection, then $O^T \Pi O$ is again a reflection, for any $O \in SO(n)$. (i.e. $O^T O = \mathbf{1}$ and $\det(O) > 0$

The composition of two reflection $\Pi_1 \circ \Pi_2$ can be written as
$$ O^T \Pi_1 \Pi_2 O = O^T \Pi O O^T \Pi_2 O = \tilde{\Pi}_1 \tilde{\Pi}_2$$
Hence the conjugation is again the composition of two reflections $\tilde{\Pi}_i = O^T \Pi_i O$.

*(I'm not an expert in this area. And as mentioned: a coordinate-free point of view is maybe better in this context.)*